# building cocoa project with maven

Tags: objective-c, maven-2, maven

i have a cocoa project and i'd like to build it with maven. is there any maven plugin for building objective-c code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have used the exec plugin to run command line cocoa  to good affect.

```
    <plugin>
          <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
          <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>1.1</version>
          <executions>
             <execution>
                  <phase>${cocoa.phase}</phase>
                  <goals>
                     <goal>exec</goal>
                  </goals>
             </execution>
          </executions>
          <configuration>
             <executable>xcodebuild</executable>
             <workingDirectory>${project.build.directory}/</workingDirectory>
          </configuration>
        </plugin>
```