# Is there a way to use Maven + Static Libraries for iPhone dependencies?

Tags: iphone, ios, maven, dependencies, static-libraries

I know that you can use static libraries to manage dependencies for iOS apps. But is there any way of using maven to manage the dependencies. I want to have a central repository for static libraries to be shared by several iOS projects and I want to use maven for handling the dependencies?

Comment: If it can help .. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1899021/building-cocoa-project-with-maven

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm currently working for SAP where we implement the whole workflow ( https://github.com/sap-production/xcode-maven-plugin )

- Resolve dependencies
- Build
- Package (IPA file)
- Upload to central repository

It is possible to **build**:

- Static libraries
- Bundles
- (Frameworks - comes with next release)

with `mvn clean install`.

It is possible to **consume**:

- Static libraries
- Bundles
- Frameworks

in your Xcode project by a simple call of `mvn initialize`. This call requires that the dependencies are available in a (local or remote) Maven repository, of course.

You can find some documentation here: http://sap-production.github.com/xcode-maven-plugin/site/ and subscribe to the mailing list http://www.freelists.org/list/maven4ios.